# Is there a way to destructure with spreader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Here were the props I originally tried to pass through to a component:

```
const allprops = {
    mainprops:{mainprops}, // object
    pageid:{pageId}, // variable
    setpageid:{setPageId}, // state function
    makerefresh:{makeRefresh} // state function
}
```

`<Navbar allprops={allprops} />`

I quickly realized I created a monster -- some nested object:

```
{mainprops: {…}, pageid: {…}, setpageid: {…}, makerefresh: {…}}

 mainprops: {mainprops: {…}}
```

after breaking my head, I came up with this:

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  const {allprops} = props;

  const {mainprops, ...userprops} = allprops
  const {mainprops:{} = {}} = mainprops;
  const {userprops:{} = {}} = userprops;
```

is there a way to turn this into a one liner? Or a loop or something faster/shorter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unnecessarily nesting your prop values inside an additional object. This:

```
const allprops = {
    mainprops:{mainprops}, // object
    pageid:{pageId}, // variable
    setpageid:{setPageId}, // state function
    makerefresh:{makeRefresh} // state function
}
```

can be made much more concise and easy to work with by changing it to:

```
const allprops = {
    mainprops,
    pageId,
    setPageId,
    makeRefresh
};
```

and by spreading that:

```
<Navbar {...allprops} />
```

And then in your child component, all you need is:

```
const Navbar = ({ mainprops, pageId, setPageId, makeRefresh }) => {
  // proceed to use mainprops, pageId, setPageId, makeRefresh
```

Comment: obviously need to update accordingly

Comment: Use consistent capitalization - `setPageId`, not `setpageid`